# plupload: Restart upload from beginning (with chunking)

Tags: javascript, plupload

Is there any way to restart a plupload upload without removing the selected files? `plupload.stop()` stops the upload, but if I start it again with `start()`, it continues where it left off. Instead, I want it to upload all files again, even those that were already uploaded.

I am using chunking, if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to loop over files and set 
file.loaded = 0;
file.status = plupload.QUEUED;